# C++/CLI Errors in Intellisense, Compiles fine

Tags: visual-studio-2012

...anyone an idea how to fix those?

Visual Studio 2011 Beta, trying to get some frameworks prepared for that and now going through a limited list of issues.

The code is:

```
String^ pUser = (System::String^) pConnectionStringBuilder["UserName"];
String^ pPass = (System::String^) pConnectionStringBuilder["Password"];
String^ pBroker = (System::String^) pConnectionStringBuilder["Broker"];
```

pConnectionStringBuilder is an instance of ConnectionStringBuilder.

The errors:

```
2   IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-CLI-array type    c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  62  39  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
3   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type   c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  62  64  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
4   IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-CLI-array type    c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  63  39  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
5   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type   c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  63  64  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
6   IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-CLI-array type    c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  64  41  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
7   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type   c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  64  66  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
8   IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object or handle-to-CLI-array type    c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  269 6   Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
9   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type   c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  269 32  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
```

and they simply make NO sense at all ;)

There are two other warnings, but quite obviously that is not an error:

1>  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic.vcxproj -> C:\Work\Tradex\Source\Debug\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic.dll
rithmicconnector.cpp(104): warning : C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'oParams'.
rithmicconnector.cpp(108): warning : C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'oLoginParams'.
1>  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

It compiles fine.

I tried to use pConnectionStringBuilder->default - guess what ;) Complains.

```
2   IntelliSense: class "System::Data::Common::DbConnectionStringBuilder" has no member "default"   c:\Work\Tradex\Source\Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic\RithmicConnector.cpp  62  65  Tradex.Connectivity.Rithmic
```

which incidentally also is wrong and it compiles ;)

I really prefer not to have Intellisense errors.

Comment: Obviously a keyboard-chair interface issue here, replace that module and your problems will go away :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intellisense for C++/CLI will often get confused and report false-positive errors. It is simply not as good as Intellisense for C#. To be fair, C++ code in general is much harder to analyze incrementally than C# code (e.g., if I add a single #define pragma into a header file, the structure of any file that imports the header file may change *completely*).

Once I start seeing spurious Intellisense errors, I usually just turn them off in the Error List window:

1. Right-click the contents of the Error List window
2. Uncheck "Show Intellisense Errors"

Comment: @NickBedford I call it reassuring. No chance of skynet here - would likely not find the nuclear rockets to start with ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are always working in C++ and are bothered by Intellisense errors, you may want to switch off permanently this Error reporting :
Tools -> Option -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> IntelliSence -> Disable Error Reporting

Comment: That's what you should do. Just disable it. Thank you so much @Manuel.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if a file ends without a newline (e.g. the last line of the include file is #endif and there's no CRLF after it) it will mess up Intellisense and cause it to flag errors.