# How to dispose an instance of a value type in C++ CLI?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, dispose, idisposable, system.memory

I'm trying to use `System.Buffers.MemoryHandle` in my C++ CLI code. I don't know to dispose it in order to 'unpin' the underlying memory.

```
void f(System::Memory<int> memory) {
    System::Buffers::MemoryHandle handle = memory.Pin();
    void* pointer = handle.Pointer; 

    // Work with the pointer

    handle.Dispose(); // error C2039: 'Dispose': is not a member of 'System::Buffers::MemoryHandle'
}
```

I've tried boxing as well, with the same error.

```
IDisposable^ disposable = handle;
disposable->Dispose(); // error C2039: 'Dispose': is not a member of 'System::IDisposable'
```

What's the proper way to dispose instances of value types?

Comment: C++/CLI was designed to be familiar to C++ programmers.  Use `delete handle;`

Comment: @HansPassant While it seems to build and run, is it really the correct way? VS displays an error: `expression must have pointer or handle type`. The C++CLI specification also requires: "a pointer type, a handle type, or a class type having a single conversion function to a pointer type".

Comment: Works fine when I compile the code.  The IntelliSense parser however can't handle it, annoying isn't it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732639/c-cli-errors-in-intellisense-compiles-fine

Comment: @HansPassant If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think you need my help anymore, just describe what you've discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans has pointed out in their comments, you can dispose the handle with `delete handle`.

The Visual Studio will complain that the `expression must have pointer or handle type`, but the code will compile and run without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `Unpin()` on the `MemoryManager`. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorymanager-1?view=net-5.0):

> Unpins pinned memory so that the garbage collector is free to move it.

Comment: I don't have any instance of `MemoryManager`. All I get is an instance of a `Memory<T>` provided by an external API.

Comment: @tearvisus In that case, you have to use the `delete` operator as Hans Passant said on the `MemoryHandle`.