# How to write a function that takes a "nested" template type as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to write a generic function that takes some map-like type, and returns all the keys in the map. I would also like the API of the function to be extremely simple, like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> stringTable;
auto stringTableKeys = keys(stringTable); // should return a std::vector<int>

std::map<std::string, double> doubleTable;
auto doubleTableKeys = keys(doubleTable); // should return a std::vector<std::string>
```

I don't want it to be tied down to std::map or std::unordered_map, nor do I want to be tied down to specific key or value types, so I tried to write the following:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, template <typename, typename...> typename Table>
std::vector<Key> keys(const Table<Key, Value>& table)
{
    std::vector<Key> keys;
    keys.reserve(table.size());
    for (const auto& [key, value] : table)
        keys.push_back(key);
    return keys;
}
```

However, if I want to use this version of the keys() function, I have to call it like this

```
auto stringTableKeys = keys<int, std::string, std::unordered_map>(stringTable);
```

How can I specify the template in the definition of keys() so that the caller does not have to specify the types?

Comment: If your function already relies on the assumption that the range-based `for` loop you've written works correctly, I'm not sure you lose that much more genericness by making use of `key_type`. E.g. just have `MapType` as a class template argument and return a `std::vector<MapType::key_type>`.

Comment: Am I missing something; your attempt seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/bexP5n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion, it turns out my code actually does work.
https://onlinegdb.com/By6hgZkMd

This is just a bug in Visual Studio 2019, I wasn't sure if it was going to work because it said it was a syntax error:
[image]

Comment: Was this a compiler error when you built the code, or did you get an error in the IDE?

Comment: @cigien no compiler error, only an IDE error.

Comment: I don't see anything saying "syntax error" in your screenshot, only some [Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732639/c-cli-errors-in-intellisense-compiles-fine/9742407#9742407) [shortcomings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-or-2017-shows-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles). Let your compiler have the final say, not Unintellinonsense. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented [compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d5heGn). However, there are a few problems with it.

It will fail to compile if the input map type uses template parameters that are different from the default. This is because the `keys` signature does not deduce template parameters of `Table` other than the first two. For example, calling `keys` like this will fail:

```
std::map<int, std::string, std::greater<int>> stringTable;
auto stringTableKeys = keys(stringTable); // the deduced type of table argument
                                          // does not match that of stringTable
```

To fix this you could adjust `keys` signature as follows:

```
template <typename Key, typename... Args,
    template <typename, typename...> typename Table>
std::vector<Key> keys(const Table<Key, Args...>& table)
{
    std::vector<Key> keys;
    keys.reserve(table.size());
    for (const auto& [key, value] : table)
        keys.push_back(key);
    return keys;
}
```

Here's the [code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E9vEn5).

However, this will still break if the type of the argument does not match the expected `template <typename, typename...> typename Table` signature, where the first template parameter denotes the key type. To mitigate this, you could use the nested `key_type` or `value_type` types that are defined by all associative containers. For example:

```
template <typename Container>
std::vector<typename Container::key_type> keys(const Container& table)
{
    std::vector<typename Container::key_type> keys;
    keys.reserve(table.size());
    for (const auto& [key, value] : table)
        keys.push_back(key);
    return keys;
}
```

or:

```
template <typename Container>
std::vector<std::remove_const_t<
    typename Container::value_type::first_type>>
    keys(const Container& table)
{
    std::vector<std::remove_const_t<
        typename Container::value_type::first_type>> keys;
    keys.reserve(table.size());
    for (const auto& [key, value] : table)
        keys.push_back(key);
    return keys;
}
```

Note that `Container::value_type` for all associative containers is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, and `std::pair` defines `first_type` and `second_type` nested typedefs to access its element types. We need to use `std::remove_const_t` to get rid of the `const` qualification of the key type.

The latter version of `keys` is especially useful as it will work not only with associative containers, but also with any sequence of `std::pair`s. See the code [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5a8roG).